# How to get walk distance (in meter) and direction in each 1/2 second in iOS Application?

Tags: ios, distance, core-motion, indoor-positioning-system

I am working on a office indoor floor plan application, and in which I have to show the office navigation with accuracy. To create a logic I will have to perform a task:

There should be a start `UIButton` in app, when I tap on that button then process should be started in which I have to find distance in meter from that point from which I have started walk and also find the direction from the that beginning point.

Can it be possible through CoreMotion framework, if yes then How ?

So please suggest me any suitable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can. But if you use the way get distance by accelerometer, its result will be terrible by my experience.

I recommend the way that check the step of the user and calculate distance by stepping.

1. Step counting
2. Calculate distance using step counting with user's info as step distance by height.

Comment: hey @jeff thanx for reply. Are you talking about CMStepCounter ? If yes than I dont know anything about CMStepCounter class. Can you explain me how this class work to count step of walk ?

Comment: No. CMStepCounter is inaccurate. It is just using for efficient battery.  
You have to find step count from calculating accelerometer information. 
Or use other open sources. The keyword is pedometer.

Actually I am making the open source to get user's status as walk(pedometer), rest, elevating and so on.

Comment: CMStepCounter may be unsuitable for a moment.

Comment: And it can be apply only iPhones using M7. I am just tested. :)

Answer (score 0):

In general it's really hard, and may be impossible using CoreMotion accelerometers. Basically, the iPhone sensors gives you acceleration that you need to integrate twice (i.e. in simple terms multiply by time^2) to get to distance. Based on my testing (and others) the results are horrible. There are techniques to improve - search for Sensor Fusion and the Kalman Filter for more info.

You'll have better luck with step counting which can be pretty accurate - although maybe not over a short distance like an office.

EDIT: I jumped to the conclusion that you wanted to use CoreMotion and accelerometers. You can also use CoreMotion and step counting. Take a look at `CM Pedometer`: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMPedometer_class/index.html (note: in iOS7 this was `CMStepCounter`).

Take a look at this answer for CMPedometer example: [CMPedometer queryPedometerDataFromDate returns error 103](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27501798/cmpedometer-querypedometerdatafromdate-returns-error-103)